# nginx proxy too many redirects SSL + Apache2

Tags: apache, nginx

I need have setup a nginx proxy for some Wordpress site under Apache and my nginx conf work only for 12 of my 15 sites.

This is the conf file I have for each sites :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name domain.com www.exemple.com;
    return 301 https://www.exemple.com;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name exemple.com www.exemple.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/exemple.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/exemple.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate 
    /etc/letsencrypt/live/exemple.com/fullchain.pem;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:100m;
    ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    ssl_session_tickets on;
    ssl_session_ticket_key /etc/nginx/ssl/ticket.key;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam4.pem;

    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers [SOME CIPHERS]

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Original-Request $request_uri;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7080;
    }
}
```

And apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:7080>
    ServerName exemple.com
    ServerAlias www.exemple.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/wp_domain

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My apache running on port 7080.
I have tested just with an index.php and no htaccess on my apache webroot but not working too...

I have not idea why just 3 of my sites not working.

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you access `http://<APACHE>:7080` directly for all 15 sites?  And are there 15 ports on the apache or they all are proxied on the same VirtualHost?

Comment: I can try this later but in theory yes (I can just access my server from another PC for now, ip filtration) but apache have 15 vhost and he does a name resolution.

Comment: Also, put your logs in debug for the ones that do not work.  Proxy does log quite a lot of details in debug mode.  After that, you will have to add more details (specific error, log messages, network errors, ...).  As it is we can`t be very specific for answers.

Comment: So I have no idea why but this morning when I've tried to access to the websites, this worked..... And it's not a problem of cache on my web browser, nginx have a cache ?